# WPF with multple tabs inside the tabs are multiple group boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabs

I have developed a wpf app using mvvm and repository design patterns. all UIs work perfectly on their own via binding with zero code behind.

Now I had to put all UIs on 1 wpf UI using tabs. Inside some tabs I have placed some UIs that were separate UIs before inside 1 tab separated by group boxes. All bindings work as expected except for the click event of combo boxes. I can't seem to get the correct ViewModel to detect/set the SelectedItem property of the combo box. When execution come to this line of code:- SelectedScope = cboJobNo.SelectedItem as Scope; SelectedItem is null. why?

Also by clicking or selecting an item in 1 combo box, how do you send that selection to another ViewModel to display its' data.

Thank you in advance

First of all I'd like to make a correction, the first ViewModel from the outer group box is sending its' data to the second ViewModel, which is in the second inner group box correctly and the second ViewModel is processing the data as expected. But the output is not displayed on the UI. The only way that the second ViewModel will display its' output is if a selection is made from the combo box in the inner group box. I have tried to explain it as clearly as I can.
Now the code:-
First group box and its binding with the first combo box inside it:
I have tried to copy and paste my code in here but it has a problem with its' indenting?

Thank you in advance

Here is parts of my code

```
                        <ComboBox 
                            Name="cboJobNo" 
                            Height="20"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            IsEditable="{Binding booIsJobNoEditable}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding booEnableDisableJobNo}"                    
                            ItemsSource="{Binding AllJobNos}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScope}"
                            SelectedIndex="{Binding intSetSelectedJobNoIndex}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="intJobNo" 
                            SelectedValuePath="intJobNo"
                            Text="{Binding SelectedScope.intJobNo}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="7,7,100.8,6.6" 
                            >
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownClosed">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction
                                        TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                        MethodName="ComboBoxSelection"
                                        />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction
                                        TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                        MethodName="EnterTabKeyPressed"
                                        />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownClosed">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction
                                        TargetObject="{Binding ViewModel[5]}"
                                        MethodName="JobNoSelection"
                                        />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </ComboBox>

    public void ComboBoxSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//Trap selections made on UI from comboboxes
        ComboBox cboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (_booSearchForScopes == true)
        {
            _ScopeData.intTotalFound = 0; //reset total records found before new search
            if (cboBox.Text != null && cboBox.Text != "")
            {
                SearchFor(cboBox.Name, cboBox.Text);
                if (cboBox.Name == "cboJobNo" && FoundMultipleScopes.Count == 1)
                {//Not working yet
                    _POrders.SelectedScope = SelectedScope;
                    _POrders.JobNoSelection(sender, e);  //passing execution to the Purchase Orders ViewModel

                    FoundMultipleScopes = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void JobNoSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//Trap selections made on UI from  from Job Number combobox
        ComboBox cboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (cboBox.Text != null && cboBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (_POrdersData.CheckAssignment(int.Parse(cboBox.Text)) > 0) //check if job number is already assigned
            {
                JobNoAssigned();
            }
            else
            {
                SearchForJobNo(cboBox, cboBox.Text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Job Number from the list.", "Select Job Number", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without a (minimal) example code it is very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: I agree, you should show some code or build a sample to reproduce your problem.

Comment: First of all I'd like to make a correction, the first ViewModel from the outer group box is sending its' data to the second ViewModel, which is in the second inner group box correctly and the second ViewModel is processing the data as expected. But the output is not displayed on the UI. The only way that the second ViewModel will display its' output is if a selection is made from the combo box in the inner group box. I have tried to explain it as clearly as I can.